# wp_query for multiple cities (multiple values in a metabox)

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

Thanks in advance for all your help!

I want to display posts (tours) that are in a specific location (city) so in my location_taxonomy.php I have a taxonomy query in the form of:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'tour',
    'meta_key'      => 'trav_tour_city',
    'meta_value'    => $term->term_id, //city id
);
```

When the key stored in the tour has only one value (one city), it displays the posts.  When the key has more than one value (multiple cities or id separated by commas), it doesn't.

How can I change the $args so the query would determine that the current city ($term->term_id) exists within the comma separated values stored in 'trav_tour_city'?

I have tried something in the line of:

```
                 // trying multiple cities 
                $args = array(
                    array(
                    'post_type'     => 'tour',
                    'meta_key'      => 'trav_tour_city',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'value'   => $term->term_id, 
                                'compare' => 'IN',
                                ),
                        ),
                    ),
                );
```

but obviously I don't know what I'm doing...  haha..

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

If your field is saved in a string format you can try using `LIKE`, like the example below:

```
 // trying multiple cities 
    $args = array(
      array(
        'post_type'   => 'tour',
         'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'meta_key'=> 'trav_tour_city',
            'value'   => (string) $term->term_id, 
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
          ),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: It didn't work though...  but why if I use this, it works?                      $args = array(
                        'post_type'     => 'tour',
                        'meta_key'      => 'trav_tour_city',
                        'meta_value'    => '87,79',
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    );

Comment: In other words... 'meta_value' => '87,79'  is reading the whole string stored in the value field... is there a way to scan that field and just find '79' within the string?

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try it again ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in another forum...

This works:

```
              $args = array (
                    'post_type' => 'tour',
                    'meta_query'=> array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'trav_tour_city', 
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            'value' => $term->term_id,
                        )
                    ),
                    'meta_key' => 'trav_tour_city',
                );
```